# How to send time to model usinig django-admin commands?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was wondering how can i send a time to django `DateTimeField` by a django-admin command class , and by time i mean the actual hour and minute not the date. thanks

my django admin command class

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    title = 'new new post'
    try:
        MyModel.objects.create(
            title=title,
            mytime= '???',
        )
        print('%s added' % (title,))
    except:
        print('error')
```

my model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
mytime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it using separate `DateField` and `TimeField` , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `DateTimeField`, you can't save only time, but you can extract the time from it later (`record.mytime.time()`).

You're looking for function [datetime.now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

```
from datetime import datetime
MyModel.objects.create(
        title=title,
        mytime=datetime.now(),
    )
```

However Django provides more convenient way how to do this - DateTimeField has a flag [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now), which sets the time automatically during saving (or `auto_now_add` if you want to set it only once when the model is created)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    mytime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now=True)
```